# Remove target from CRS rule based on multiple criteria

Tags: apache, mod-security

I have a WordPress site. The WP site is running behind a reverse proxy (Apache 2.4.37) with ModSecurity 2.9.7, and the OWASP Core Ruleset 3.1.0.

The WP site has a home-built theme, that requires periodical edits (updating the token in a shortcode) to keep working (.*.. yes, I know! But it wasn't me that did that ...*). Naturally enough, that editing trips up ModSecurity.

I do have the rule exclusions that allows that editing -- but I want to restrict it to an IP-range, and also to the relevant `REQUEST_URI` and `REQUEST_HEADERS:Referer`.

First try:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" "phase:1,chain,nolog,pass,id:20010,ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=933100;ARGS:newcontent"
 SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Referer "@rx (?i)^https://example\.com/wp-admin/theme-editor\.php.*" "chain"
 SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch 1.2.3.0/23,1.2.5.128/25"
```

This indeed opens the WAF/removes the target, but does not restrict to the IP-range -- nor to `Referer`, probably. Investigating, I found a old comment pointing out that *non-disruptive* actions are executed as soon as the rule matches.  `ctl` is a non-disruptive action ...

Second try -- move the `ctl` action to the last rule in the chain:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@beginsWith /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" "phase:1,chain,nolog,pass,id:20010"
 SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Referer "@rx (?i)^https://example\.com/wp-admin/theme-editor\.php.*" "chain"
 SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "@ipMatch 1.2.3.0/23,1.2.5.128/25" "ctl:ruleRemoveTargetById=933100;ARGS:newcontent"
```

This do not remove the target, in either case (external or internal).

Is there a way to make the chain approach work, with the `ctl` action? Or is there an alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

ModSecurity Core Rule Set *Developer on Duty* here. I've just tested your rule exclusion chain and it works for me. If I had to guess why it's not working for you, I'd start looking at that regular expression.

Replace the regular expression with `@unconditionalMatch` and see if it starts working for you. E.g.:

```
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Referer "@unconditionalMatch" "chain"
```

If **that** doesn't work then try replacing the `@ipMatch` operator in the same way. You'll quickly discover which rule is causing your trouble.

Also, CRS version 3.1.0 is [unsupported](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/blob/v3.4/dev/SECURITY.md) and [considered to be insecure](https://coreruleset.org/20210630/cve-2021-35368-crs-request-body-bypass/). At the very least, you should consider updating to the latest minor release of the 3.1.x line, which is [v3.1.2](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/releases/tag/v3.1.2).